# Set variable storing text as a .get_group category

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to use a variable storing text or a list as a category for .get_group.

Something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("HondaSales.xlsx")

brand = ["honda", "acura"]
year = "2020"

brands1 = df.groupby(["Brand","Year"]) 
honda = brands1.get_group([brand, year])
sales = honda["UNI_VEH"]
salessum, = sales.sum()
print('Sales of', brand, 'in', year,':', salessum)
```

I´ve tried it as such, but I get this error: ValueError: must supply a tuple to get_group with multiple grouping keys

perhaps something is wrong with parentheses

Answer (score -1):

Here is the error:
honda = brands1.get_group([brand, year]),  please share more info, because it suits you.